# Problemas para atualizar página e deslogar usuário após periodo inativo

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html5, ajax

Preciso deslogar o usuário após um tempo inativo. 
Consigo atualizar e destruir a sessão porém não está funcionando conforme a minha necessidade. Que no caso é que o php não identifique como uma atividade realizada pelo usuário a atualização automática do javascript após o tempo.

Vou inserir como faço a atualização da página automaticamente com JS.

```
var refreshIntervalId = setInterval(fname, 180000);


function fname() {
  window.location.reload(true);
  // window.location.reload(); use this if you do not remove cache
}
```

Agora vou mostrar como está a minha função de deslogar no php, ná página de validação eu chamo a variável global:

```
$tempolimite = 3000;
//fim das configurações de fusu horario e limite de inatividade//

   // aqui ta o seu script de autenticação no momento em que ele for validado você seta as configurações abaixo.//
   // seta as configurações de tempo permitido para inatividade//
    $_SESSION['registro'] = time(); // armazena o momento em que autenticado //
    $_SESSION['limite'] = $tempolimite; // armazena o tempo limite sem atividade //
   // fim das configurações de tempo inativo//
```

Agora onde realmente eu verifico as coisas na minha página principal:

```
$registro = $_SESSION['registro'];
 $limite = $_SESSION['limite'];

 if($registro)// verifica se a session  registro esta ativa
 {
  $segundos = time() - $registro;
 }
 // fim da verificação da session registro

 /* verifica o tempo de inatividade 
 se ele tiver ficado mais de 300 segundos sem atividade ele destroi a session
 se não ele renova o tempo e ai é contado mais 300 segundos*/
 if($segundos>$limite)
 {
  session_destroy();
  die( "Sua seção expirou.");

 }
 else{
  $_SESSION['registro'] = time();
 }
 // fim da verificação de inatividade
```

Muito obrigado desde já comunidade, e me desculpem se isso for algo muito simples de se fazer, porém eu realmente estou no começo e isso é tudo muito novo pra mim! Fiquem com Deus e desculpe tb se está pergunta for muito óbvia!

Att,
Renan Godoy

Comment: Dá uma lida nestas diretivas de configuração:
session.gc_maxlifetime na página: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/session.configuration.php Pelo que entendi, você precisa expirar a sessão após um tempo X, se ela não foi atualizada pelo browser, e não considerar se foi feito o acesso somente pelo AJAX.

Comment: Romeu Gomes seria possíve por favor, se não for pedir muito, um exemplo de usuabilidade desta opção no meu porblema, volto a repetir sou novo no mundo da programação, muito obrigado mesmo!